# How to choose text we input in a dropdown using vba in selenium?

Tags: vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

So this is my first time writing `VBA` `Selenium` code based on what i learned from youtube. Basically it works great but then i have a minor hiccup that i couldn't resolve until now.
The problem is i couldn't choose what i input in the dropdown box.

This is the condition after i paste the agent code that i wanted (https://prnt.sc/1yrd0m6)

The agent code that i wanted is on the list but it's located on the bottom (https://prnt.sc/1yrdbq3)

So how do i choose that specific agent code?

Can anyone help me?

`HTML`

```
<input type="text" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" spellcheck="false" class="select2-input ignore-validation" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="select2-results-1" id="s2id_autogen1_search" placeholder="" aria-activedescendant="select2-result-label-10200">
```

`My Code`

```
Option Explicit
Private cd As selenium.ChromeDriver
Sub Reassign()
    
    Dim FindBy As New selenium.By
    Dim lr As Long, i As Long
    Dim t As Long
    Dim Agent As Variant
    Dim opl As selenium.WebElement
    
    Set cd = New selenium.ChromeDriver
    
    cd.Start
    cd.Get "http://ekiwi.id.tmsapp.net/index.php"
    cd.Wait (3000)
    
    'If different user please change username and password
    cd.FindElementByName("username").SendKeys "teamlead333@ekiwiID.com"
    cd.FindElementByName("password").SendKeys "dePMlQ60jL"
    cd.FindElementByCss("#loginFormDiv > form > div:nth-child(6) > button").Click
    cd.Wait (3000)
    cd.FindElementByCss("#sidebarnav > li:nth-child(5) > a > i").ClickDouble
    cd.Wait (3000)
    cd.FindElementByCss("#sidebarnav > li:nth-child(5) > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a > i").Click
    cd.Wait (3000)
    cd.FindElementByCss("#appnav > ul > div > button.btn.module-buttons.btn-bhs.btn-filter-header.filter > span").Click
    cd.Wait (3000)
    
With Sheet1

lr = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
Agent = Sheet1.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row

t = 1

    For i = 3 To lr
    
    'Clear Filter
    cd.FindElementByCss("#appnav > ul > div > button.btn.module-buttons.btn-bhs.filter.btn-clear-filter > i").Click
    cd.Wait (3000)
    'Paste leadid from excel
    cd.FindElementByCss("#tblMailList0_wrapper > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div.dataTables_scrollHead > div > table > thead > tr.bhs-filter.ddd > th:nth-child(2) > span > input").SendKeys .Cells(i, "B")
    'Enter function
    cd.FindElementByCss("body").Click
    cd.Wait (4000)
    'Select leadid by checkbox
    cd.FindElementByCss("#tblMailList0 > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1) > input").Click
    cd.Wait (3000)
    'Reassign leadid
    cd.FindElementByCss("#btnReassign").Click
    cd.Wait (2000)
    cd.FindElementByCss("#s2id_selected-agent > a > span.select2-arrow > b").Click
    cd.Wait (2000)
    cd.FindElementByCss(".select2-input.ignore-validation.select2-focused").SendKeys .Cells(i, "D")
    cd.Wait (2000)
    cd.FindElementByClass("select2-result-label").Click
    cd.Wait (2000)
    cd.FindElementById("add-to-order-list").Click
    cd.Wait (2000)
    cd.FindElementByCss("#assign-agent").Click
    cd.Wait (2000)
    
    
    t = t + 1
    
Next

End With

cd.Close
MsgBox "Macro Done"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

you replace the line  (not tested because no vba)

```
cd.FindElementByCss(".select2-input.ignore-validation.select2-focused").SendKeys .Cells(i, "D")
```

by

```
cd.FindElementByXPath("//ul[@id='select2-results-1']//div[text()='agentbk12']").click()
```

i have tested on python its functional, i think its the right syntax in VBA, you just adapt the creation of string xpath with your content of cellule excel

my python:

```
#Reassign leadid open popup
cd.find_element_by_css_selector("#btnReassign").click()
time.sleep(2)
#click inside popup to open all choices
cd.find_element_by_css_selector("#s2id_selected-agent > a > span.select2-arrow > b").click()
time.sleep(2)
#select the choice with text agentbk12 and click it to set the field
cd.find_element_by_xpath ("//ul[@id='select2-results-1']//div[text()='agentbk12']").click()
```

Comment: i used your code but it shows error code

Run-Time error '59':
UnexpectedTagNameError
Unexpected tag name
Expected=select
Got=input

Comment: ok i understant what type of dropdown is..with autocomplete..see my fixed ansxer

Comment: now it's
Run-time error '7':
NoSuchElementError
Element not found for
XPath=//ul[@id='select2-results-1']//div[text()='agentbk12']

Comment: can i use my cursor to highlight the one i wanted to choose and click?

Comment: yes yo coould and send enter key but  i dont undesratnd why the xpath ts not functional could you type the xpath in the inspect of your html?  could you show the code you have written?

Comment: just to see the xpath is right i have done a little video you could download (best quality) https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_TkLGqPx_8x5Qs7wtaoiOQmehjJvjyQs/view?usp=sharing

Comment: This is the code i wrote

cd.FindElementById("s2id_autogen1_search").SendKeys .Cells(i, "D")
cd.Wait (2000)
cd.FindElementByXPath("//ul[@id='select2-results-1']//div[text()='agentbk12']").Click

Comment: i dont understand your line with Cells(i, "D")??? for me its agentbk12, i have written my python code in the answer